# Loadind NYU depth v2 dataset in python

Tags: python, kinect, mat, depth

I have tried to verify a depth algorithm and therefore I need some good data.

I want to use the `NYU Depth V2 dataset` (http://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html).

I have the labeled dataset but the file is in '.mat' format.

While using h5py, the color images values I'm getting is

```
[[ 255 255 255],[255 255 255] ,[255 255 255]...
```

Is there a possibility to save the color files in a png-file or load them with actual values, without scaling them in python?

def image_loader():

```
# data path
path_to_depth = './nyu_depth_v2_labeled.mat'

# read mat file
f = h5py.File(path_to_depth)

batch_size=6

pred = np.zeros((6,480,640,3))
gt = np.zeros((6,480,640,1))    
for i in range(batch_size):

    # read 0-th image. original format is [3 x 640 x 480], uint8
    img = f['images'][i]

    # reshape
    img_ = np.empty([480, 640, 3])
    img_[:,:,0] = img[0,:,:].T
    img_[:,:,1] = img[1,:,:].T
    img_[:,:,2] = img[2,:,:].T

    # read corresponding depth (aligned to the image, in-painted) of size [640 x 480], float64
    depth = f['depths'][i]

    depth_ = np.empty([480, 640])
    depth_[:,:] = depth[:,:].T

    pred[i,:,:,:] = img_
    gt[i,:,:,0] = depth_ 

return pred, gt
```

Comment: Those are the 8-bit RGB values for each pixel in each image. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I get that those are 8-bit RGB values, but I'm getting all values as 255. No variation as there are in RGB images.

Comment: [255, 255, 255] is a white pixel. If all pixels show this value, something is wrong with your data. h5py does not scale data as far as I know, and certainly not everything to 255...

Comment: Do you have a code which could help me load the color images ? @Dux

Comment: Your data is not in a color image file (e.g. .png) but in a h5py file, correct? What is the data right after you load it, e.g. what is `f['images'][4][:, 100,100]`?

Comment: Thanks. I was indexing it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and when I tried to load it in PIL, the color lies just in the middle of the image. I found some solution using `ndarray.transpose` to make the shape from (3, 640, 480) to (480, 640, 3). Then I was able to view the image correctly.

```py
Image.fromarray(f['images'][0].transpose(2,1,0))
```